# I've added breeze to my webapi but it still not adding the custom $id and $type properties

Tags: c#, breeze, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to add Breeze to my .Net Core 2.2 webapi and I can't figure out what I'm missing.  To troubleshoot I've created a very simple webapi that returns 1 item.  This works but breeze isn't adding it's custom properties to my entities.

I've added [BreezeQueryFilter] to my controller but the $id and $type properties are not being added to my entities.

I've create a simple repository with what I have so far.

https://github.com/wstow/SimpleBreeze

Thanks

My Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[BreezeQueryFilter]
public class OrderController : Controller
{
    private OrderContext _context;

    private OrderManager PersistenceManager;

    public OrderController(OrderContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
        PersistenceManager = new OrderManager(context);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Metadata()
    {
        return Ok(PersistenceManager.Metadata());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<ReqStatus> Status()
    {
        return PersistenceManager.Context.ReqStatus;
    }

}
```

My Manager

```
 public class OrderManager : EFPersistenceManager<OrderContext>
 {
    public OrderManager(OrderContext orderContext) : base(orderContext) { }
}
```

My Context

```
public class OrderContext : DbContext
    {
        public OrderContext()
        {
            //Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            // Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public OrderContext(DbContextOptions<OrderContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        { }

        public DbSet<ReqStatus> ReqStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the JSON serialization settings.  [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help) is highly configurable, and you need to use the right settings to communicate properly with the Breeze client.

To make this easy, Breeze has a configuration function to change the settings to good defaults.  You call it from your `Startup.cs`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

      var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvc();

      mvcBuilder.AddJsonOptions(opt => {
        var ss = JsonSerializationFns.UpdateWithDefaults(opt.SerializerSettings);
      });
      mvcBuilder.AddMvcOptions(o => { o.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionFilter()); });
...
```

The documentation is lacking, but you can see what `JsonSerializationFns` does by [looking in the Breeze code](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/master/AspNetCore/Breeze.Core/JsonSerializationFns.cs).

The last line adds an exception filter that wraps server-side validation errors so that the Breeze client can handle them.  You can see what it does [here](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/master/AspNetCore/Breeze.AspNetCore.NetCore/GlobalExceptionFilter.cs).